# How to automatically set each new file in utf-8 without BOM?

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++

win xp sp3
notepad++ v 6.6.7

Settings - Preferences - New Document
UTF-8 without BOM - is chosen
Apply to opened ANSI files - is checked

Still when I create a new file and check in `Encode` - `Encode in ANSI` is marked and not `Encode in utf-8 without BOM`.

How can I  automatically set `Encode in utf-8 without BOM` on each new created file?

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it, it's a small 'undesirable feature' with empty files but it will actually work as you want.

If you open a blank text document then, as you say, it will show `Encode - Encode in ANSI` but if you add some text (even just a single character), save it, then re-open the text file it will correctly show `Encode - Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.

You should also find that if you actually create the new file from within Notepad++ (ie `File - New`) it will correctly show `Encode - Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.